# SAS calculation of duration when a variable takes on a specific value

Tags: sas, duration

I have a dataset where I want to calculate the duration of multiple welfare spells for each id in SAS.

**Start** is defined by the variable y_xxxx taking on the value ’welfare’ where the former 4 y_xxxx isn’t equal to 'welfare' for each id.

**End** is defined by the variable y_xxxx taking on the value ‘welfare’ where the following 4 y_xxxx isn’t equal to ‘welfare’. If the following 4 y_xxxx's takes on the value 'other' this spell has to be deleted not the entire observation.

**Duration** = end-start+1

Each id can have multiple spells of ‘welfare’, which satisfies the above restrictions. The data looks like this (except that the variable y_xxxx is recorded until y_1548 in the real dataset).

```
ID  y_0950   y_0951   y_0952   y_0953   y_1001    y_1002    y_1003   ...  y_1015
01  other    other    other    other    welfare   welfare   welfare  ... 
02  welfare  welfare  welfare  other    other     other     other    ...
03  
04
...
N  other   other     other    other    welfare   welfare   welfare  ...
```

I can calculate the duration for the first spell, see code below, but I can’t figure out how to continue for the next spells for each id without repeating the same code over and over again.

```
%let uger=y_0950--y_1015;
%let welfare='welfare';
%let other='other';

/*Start welfare spell*/
data mydata;
set data;
array y(*) &uger;
do j=5 to 19 until (start);
if  y(j-1) ne &welfare and  
y(j-2) ne &welfare and  
y(j-3) ne &welfare and  
y(j-4) ne &welfare and
y(j) eq &welfare 
then start=j;
end;
if start>0 then output;
run;

/*end welfare spell*/
data mydata1;
set mydata;
array y(*) &uger;
do j=start to 19 until(ends);
if y(j) ne &welfare and
y(j+1) ne &welfare and
y(j+2) ne &welfare and
y(j+3) ne &welfare
then ends=j-1;
end;
/*other*/
do k=start to 19 until(other);
if y(k) eq &other and
y(k+1) eq &other and
y(k+2) eq &other and
y(k+3) eq &other
then other=k-1;
end;
if ends=. then censor=1;
if ends=. then ends=19;
if other >0 then delete;
duration= ends-start+1;
run;
```

I would like to end up with data like below (not corresponding to the data example above)

```
ID  start  end  duration  censor   
01  5      10   6         0         
01  15     19   5         1  
02  6      12   7         0
03  ..
04  ..
04  ..
..
N
```

Comment: Censor indicates that the last observed period is "welfare" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `censor` indicates that the last observed period is "welfare", this should solve your problem.

There is more than one solution to this problem, but the key here is the use of `output` when you reach a value "other" following a value "welfare", and resetting the other variables to missing (could have been to 0 as well) after the `output`, so you can start afresh.

Another thing to be aware of is the particularities of the last element in the vector. See my comments in the code below.

### Create Sample Data

```
data welfare;
  input ID 
        y_0950 $ 
        y_0951 $
        y_0952 $
        y_0953 $
        y_1001 $
        y_1002 $
        y_1003 $;
  datalines;
01 other welfare welfare other other welfare welfare welfare
02 welfare welfare welfare other other other other
03 welfare welfare other other welfare welfare welfare
04 welfare other welfare welfare other welfare other
run;
```

### Calculate Periods of Welfare

```
/* add y_: to the drop if you don't need them */
data welfare_periods (drop=i); 
  format ID start end duration censor 8.;
  set welfare;
  array y(*) y_:;    
  censor = 0;
  start = .;
  end = .;
  duration = .;

  /* Loop over every column y_... */
  do i = 1 to (dim(y)-1);
    if y(i) = "welfare" then do;
      /* Check if we have a new start */
      if duration = . then do;
        start = i;
        end = i; /* We'll increment this later if need be. */
        duration = 1; /* We'll increment this later if need be. */
      end;
      else if y(i-1) = "welfare" then do;
        end = end + 1;
        duration = duration + 1;
      end;
    end;

    /* When y(i) = "other" */
    else if y(i) = "other" then do;
      if duration > 0 then do;
        /* Output the row and reset the start/end/duration variables */
        output;
        start = .;
        end = .;
        duration = .;
      end;
    end;

    /* Decide what to do when we reach last element minus 1 */
    /* We know here that y(i) = "welfare", since the last */
    /* "else if" block took care of y(i)'s equal to "other" */
    if i = dim(y) - 1 and duration > 0 then do;
      if y(i+1) = "welfare" then do;
        end = end + 1;
        duration = duration + 1;
        censor = 1;
        output;
      end;
      else if y(i+1) = "other" then output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

### Results

[image]

Comment: Yes, censor indicates the last observation is welfare. Thank you, for your answer, it was a great help.

Comment: You're welcome Cornelia, it was an interesting problem to solve :)